# How to get interval of time without using timestamp?

Tags: nearprotocol

I want voting system where voting phase ends after a week. I don't want to use block_timestamp. What near_sdk env should I use?

```
pub fn block_index() -> BlockHeight
```

There are `epoch_height` and `block_index`, what should I use? I have heard that `block_index` may not be continuous and can have missing numbers. Is that true?

https://docs.rs/near-sdk/3.1.0/near_sdk/env/

Comment: Can you explain why you won't want to use block_timstamp?

Comment: Other blockchain use blocknumber, it's a bit easier to implement, that's why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, `block_timestamp` is used in all the applications.

In a few cases `block_index` is used, but there are indeed no guarantees that it blocks will be produced every second and that it won't change in the future in some way.

`block_index` can indeed not have all consecutive numbers when some blocks were not produced, but that also means more time elapsed as there is target time period per each block (which is 1 second right now). E.g. if there is block 1111 and next block is 1113 - that means roughly ~2 seconds have passed between these two blocks.